# how to make tensorflow pb file of the modified model by using pb file of pre-trained graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to make image retrieval application by using tensorflow. I want to use a pre-trained Inception v3 model for feature extraction.
I got the pb file of Incetion v3 from tensorflow mobile demo.
BUT this model is for classification. so I have to use the model without a few layers at the end of the model.

My code is like this..

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph and returns it 
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        # The name var will prefix every op/nodes in your graph
        # Since we load everything in a new graph, this is not needed
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    return graph

graph = load_graph('tensorflow_inception_graph.pb')
inception_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input:0')
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/avgpool0/reshape:0')
output_feature = tf.stop_gradient(y) # It's an identity function

# Saving
sess = tf.Session()

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('./test5')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["tag"], signature_def_map= {
        "model": tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
            inputs= {"x": x},
            outputs= {"finalnode": y})
        })
builder.save()
```

I want to make pb file again after making the model for feature extraction.
(I want to make pb file after transforming the model)

When I run my code, I got this

```
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to save.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: b'./test8\\saved_model.pb'
```

Also I got error when I load the model I made.

Comment: What's the error when you load the model?